# JavaScript Function: Capitalize First Letter and All Letters Following _ in Input Str of Function

Tags: javascript, regex, string, function, uppercase

Let's say I have a function that takes a string input.

the string input looks like this: "first_time_run"

Below is my code

```
function changeInput (str) {
  // your code here
  return str[0].toUpperCase()+id.slice(1)
}
```

The code above returns `First_time_run` when I want it to return `First_Time_Run`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to code for the `and All Letters Following _` condition

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but if you're trying to capitalize things for display purposes on a page, i'd just use `text-transform` css. Not sure if that's what you're doing here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your function like this. It split your input by `_`, capitalize first letter of each and then rejoin:

```js
var input = "first_time_run";

function changeCap(str) {
  // your code here
  return str[0].toUpperCase()+str.slice(1)
}

function changeInput(str) {
  return str.split("_").map((val) => changeCap(val)).join("_");
}

console.log(changeInput(input))
```

Or you can replace with regex:

```js
var input = "first_time_run";


function changeInput(str) {
  return str.replace(/(^\w|(?<=_)\w)/g, (l)=> l.toUpperCase())
}

console.log(changeInput(input))
```

Comment: thank u; in your second example what is (1)? is that a one?

Comment: it's letter "l" not 1, it just the variable name represent the first letter of string or after the `_` as captured in the regex.

Comment: `(l)` is the start of an arrow. `(l) => ...` is equivalent to `function(l){ ... }` at least in this case. For more info see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following expanded example:

1. Since you need to uppercase more the one character we need to loop through all of them
2. We can reconstruct the string with a loop and use a flag to indicate if the next character should be uppercase.
3. Per your example, the special character we need to detect is an underscore `_`
4. The outcome will be all character after an `_` been uppercase.

```js
function changeInput(str) {
  var newStr = '';
  // Uppercase the first letter by default
  var upperCaseNext = true;
  
  // Loop to reconstruct the input string letter by letter
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (upperCaseNext) {
      // Uppercase the current character and add it to the new string
      newStr += str[i].toUpperCase();
      // Reset the flag
      upperCaseNext = false;
    } else {
      // Add the current character as is
      newStr += str[i];
      // If current character is _ then enable flag to uppercase the next character
      upperCaseNext = str[i] === '_';
    }
  }

  return newStr;
}

let test = 'first_time_run';
console.log(test, '=>', changeInput(test))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this without regex(since you haven't specifically mentioned you wanted to only use regex):

```
function convertToFirstUpper(sInput) {
    return sInput.split('_').reduce((sPrev, sWord) => `${sPrev}_${sWord[0].toUpperCase()}${sWord.slice(1)}`, '').slice(1)
}

let sResult = convertToFirstUpper('first_time_run');

 console.log(sResult);
```

I typed this on my phone so its hard to format the code.

Answer (score 0):

You also could loop through your code with a for loop and use an if condition that only will capitalize the first letter if it's lowercase.

The key here is showing what type of character splits the characters of the array you want to capitalize, and then rejoin the characters into a string separated by that same underscore character.

```
let result = "first_time_run";

function makeFirstUpper(result1) {
  let newValue = result1.split('_');

  for(let i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++){
    if(newValue[i].charAt(0) == newValue[i].charAt(0).toLowerCase()){
    newValue[i] = newValue[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newValue[i].substring(1);
    }
  }
  return newValue.join('_');
}

console.log(makeFirstUpper(result));
```